# stacked create service authentication is failing for me

Tags: stacked, flutter-stacked

when I try to create service using stacked_cli: ^1.3.0 , i am getting the following error:

`Unhandled exception:`
`Invalid argument(s): Could not find an option named "template".`
`#0      ArgResults.[] (package:args/src/arg_results.dart:65:7)`
`#1      CreateServiceCommand.run (package:stacked_cli/src/commands/create/create_service_command.dart:46:37)`
`#2      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:27)`
`#3      CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:122:25)`
`#4      new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:302:31)`
`#5      CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:122:14)`
`#6      main (file:///Users/mohamedbashir/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/stacked_cli-1.3.0/bin/stacked.dart:59:12)`
`<asynchronous suspension>`

however, there are no issues in creating views. I am only getting errors when I try to create a service

I tried deactivating and activating the stacked cli but the problem persists

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey, I will look into this now and push an update.

Answer (score 1):

Update to 1.3.1 it's fixed in that version.